# Enable event loop group logging in Micronaut Netty

Tags: java, rest, logging, netty, micronaut

I have a micronaut app say **MicronautAppB** which accepts requests from **AppA** via feign. In a very specific use case MicronautAppB delays picking up requests from AppA to process. The use case is somewhat like this

```
AppA makes request1 to MicronautAppB. 

While processing request1 MicronautAppB makes a 
request2 to AppA as it needs some data. 

AppA while processing request2 makes a 
request3, request4 to MicronautAppB. 

Once request3 and request 4 are served 
from MicronautAppB. 

request2 gets served by AppA and 
MicronautAppB serves request1.
```

In this use case MicronautAppB is intermittenly delaying to pick **request3** or **request4**. This delay is adding up to request1 and it is overshooting the SLA.

Is there a way to enable event loop group logs in micronaut to actually check what is happening. Any logs that say if the request is waiting to get picked up as all threads are busy or is it because of some other IO that the thread is in blocked state.?